# If $n^4a_n^3\to 0$, show$|a_n|\le\frac{1}{n^{4/3}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If I deduced that $$n^4a_n^3\to0$$

How do I deduce that $$|a_n|\le\frac{1}{n^{4/3}}$$

Is it because for a sufficiently large n, $n^4a_n^3=1$? I can't really figure this one out.

*Other Information*

The question requires me to show that $a_n$ is absolutely convergent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the definition of the limit - 
If $n^4a_n^3\rightarrow0$ then there is an $n_0$ s.t. for any $n>n_0$ $|n^4a_n^3-0|<1$. Now use this inequality to deduce what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Assume not. Then $$\left|n^{4}a_{n}^{3}\right|>\frac{n^{4}}{n^{4}}=1.$$